# Read multiple files from Unix folder and extract key value pair using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, tuples

Reading multiple files from Unix directory. I am trying to read multiple files stored in Unix folder and extract Key Value Pair after this bit of text "input1".

Each Files consist data in below formats:-

input1 = {'hostname' : 'host', 'port' : '22', 'basedn' : 'CN=Users', 'bindusername' : 'admin']

```
Need to read dict and extract Key Value pair and print in below format:
    
    Col1   Col2
    xyz   123
    abc   456
    def   756



path = '/home/var/testfile/'
basepath =os.path.dirname(path)
with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_file():
               fn=entry.name
def f(fn):
     with open(fn) as f:
        for s in f:
            data = pd.DataFrame()
            key = []
            value = []
            for k, v in s.items():
                key.append(k)
                value.append(v)
            data["Col1"] = key
            data["Col2"] = value
            print(data)
            
Above script does wotk when for a single file , but when i loop to read all the files from the folder , it stucked .
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important to demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your problem, usually by posting the formatted **text** version of your code and highlighting where you are stuck. If you do, others will help.

Comment: Assuming that the data you posted is **exactly** the data that is in your file, most importantly using "single quotes'. Then you will want to `open()` your file `read()` the contents into a `variable` and then `ast.literal_eval()` that `variable` giving you a python `dict` that you can use to print the keys and values with a `for` loop and `variable_as_dict.items()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'xyz':'123' , 'abc':'456','def':'765'}
data = pd.DataFrame()
key = []
value = []
for k, v in dic.items():
    key.append(k)
    value.append(v)
data["Col1"] = key
data["Col2"] = value
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Arun ! When i am trying to read from a file using your script , It doesnt work . Could you please advise . 
My file consist below data :-
input1 = {'hostname' : 'host', 'port' : '22', 'basedn' : 'CN=Users', 'bindusername' : 'admin']

Comment: basepath = (r"C:\Users\test1")
with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_file():
               fn=entry.name
def f(fn):
     with open(fn) as f:
        for s in f:
            data = pd.DataFrame()
            key = []
            value = []
            for k, v in s.items():
                key.append(k)
                value.append(v)
            data["Col1"] = key
            data["Col2"] = value
            print(data)

Comment: @Geek_Coder update your original question with your code (using the code formatting tool),

Comment: Using `pandas` to print a dict is such an overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Here try this?

```
import pandas as  pd
dic1={'xyz':'123' , 'abc':'456','def':'765'}
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Col1']=[val for val,key in dic1.items()] #=== All keys in dic1
data['Col2']=[key for val,key in dic1.items()] #=== All Values in dic1
print(data)
```

prints:

```
  Col1 Col2
0  xyz  123
1  abc  456
2  def  765
```

Comment: Thanks sujay , When i am trying to read from a file using your script , It doesnt work . Could you please advise . My file consist below data :- input1 = {'hostname' : 'host', 'port' : '22', 'basedn' : 'CN=Users', 'bindusername' : 'admin']

Comment: My code :- basepath = (r"C:\Users\test1") with os.scandir(basepath) as entries: for entry in entries: if entry.is_file(): fn=entry.name def f(fn): with open(fn) as f: for s in f: data = pd.DataFrame() key = [] value = [] for k, v in s.items(): key.append(k) value.append(v) data["Col1"] = key data["Col2"] = value print(data)

Comment: Using `pandas` to print a dict is such an overkill...